# Alternative methods for maintaining JavaScript source

Tags: javascript, performance, code-organization

I'm looking for other options for maintaining my personal JavaScript namespace.  The problem I'm having boils down code *Organization* Vs. *Performance*.  I would simply LOVE to be able to separate major sections of my code into a more "traditional" style.  But I haven't because if I were to do that I would probably quadruple the amount of HTTP requests I send out.

Essentially I am including two different js files.  `jQUery/jQueryUI/my namespace` in one and my implementation in the other.  Great for performance in my web-apps... but looking at my JavaScript source makes me scared, confused, and horrified all at the same time.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the difference.

When developing separate out the source files. You will have a large number of HTTP requests and lots of files.

When deploying compile the source into one JavaScript file.